# Special Characters in Sitecore Item Names (EXM)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-exm

I'd like to create a new Sitecore item using a name that contains German characters. At the moment every time the name contains "ä" "ö" or "ü" Sitecore complains about the name and prevents me from creating it.

I can see the same problem using the EXM module (E-mail Experience Manager). I cannot create any newsletters that contain special characters.

Is there any way I could change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the regular expression which is used for the "Name" field validation.

You can resolve the issue by replacing the `ItemNameValidation` setting value with the following value:
`^[\w\*\$]*[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ\][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$` or add a new patch config file to your project which is recomended.

```
<setting name="ItemNameValidation" set:value="^[\w\*\$]*[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ\][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```